# Google translate header bar appearing in IE9 when not translating - also drop down doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, translation, google-translate

Unfortunately, I don't have this on a live server anywhere at the moment but I'm having issues in IE9 with google translate inserting a div at the top of the page and the dropdown not opening on click. There are no JS errors so I'm not sure what's going on.

Has anyone seen this or knows what I might take a look at to fix it?

[image]

The div that is showing at the top of the page normally pops up in a popover when you hover a translated word. Currently in IE9 it's showing before even translating the page.

[image]

Comment: wait... is this bar unintended? meaning it's showing up but you're not including it? please clarify.

Comment: All I've done is included the google translate snippet - that bar is showing all the time even before translating anything. It normally pops up in a popover window when you hover over a translated word (see updated screenshot in question)

Comment: is the script being blocked?

Comment: Console shows no JS errors - but IE debugger is a POS - any suggestions for debugging IE?

Comment: choose the network tab, click start capturing, then reload the page.